# jQuery ajax returns on all page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to make something simple but the return of AJAX is coming on all page not to the DIV I want to.

Here is my code PHP: **file_ajax.php**

```
<?php
require_once "../../funct/cfg.php";
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
if(fileDB($_POST['id'])){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var albhost="albup.ex";
var albbg="111111";
var albvi="2013";
var albid="'.$_POST['id'].'";
var albw=326;
var alblight="D69E9E";
var albfront="C4C4C4";
var albvol=80;
var albas="true";
var albdownb="0";
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://albup.ex/api/explayer/embed.js">
</script>';
exit;
}
}
?>
```

and the file ajax: ajax.js

```
function PrewThis(id,style){
var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&style=' +  style;
$("#fileprev").removeClass();
$("#fileprev").show().addClass(style);
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/file_ajax.php",
          data: dataString,
          context: "#fileprev",
          error: function(){ $("#sidebox").append("SOMETHING ERROR") },
          success: function(html){
          $("#fileprev").append(html);
         }
    });
}
```

And the call is:

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="PrewThis('MRuw2ZbMXj','oranger'); return false" 
class="oranger">Sean Paul - Got 2 Luv U (Feat. Alexis Jordan)</a>
```

Please someone help ?

Comment: **WARNING!** You're passing unfiltered, unvalidated user input right back out (`$_POST['id']`). This can create a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability, easily allowing malicious users to hijack your site for their own purposes. Please add appropriate validation to user input and filtering on output of user-provided data.

Comment: @Charles i know that i just need to return the value im creating in it and i will but the resoults when i click the link is comming in all pages and removes my html code just to that embed code 

what can ja do to put this embed to my wanted div that is the point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a guess, but I think this line is the source of your problem...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://albup.ex/api/explayer/embed.js">
```

As it states in the jQuery docs: "If html is specified, any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string."

It seems possible that the included script's output is blowing up your page.

Nothing else in your code seems to indicate a problem. It all looks good otherwise, but then I haven't seen your HTML source.